# How to test response StatusCode of MVC Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, mstest

I want to write unit test for my controller.

I want to check the response codes of actions. For example, Post action should return `201`, get should return `200`, etc.

However, the Action method return `IActionResult`. How do I get response code from the `ActionResult`?

```
 //setup
 MyController controller = CreateController<MyController>();

 //action
 var actionResult = controller.Post(dafXml);

 //assert
 ???
```

I don't want to check the type of action result since I care only about the status code. for example, `201` can be achieved by `CreatedAtAction`, `CreatedAtRoute` or with custom `ObjectResult`...

Answer (score 11):

[FluentAssertions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions) provide an elegant way to assert controller response codes. See examples below.

```
// 200
actionResult.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>()
    .Which.StatusCode.Should().Be((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);

// 201
actionResult.Should().BeOfType<CreatedResult>()
    .Which.StatusCode.Should().Be((int)HttpStatusCode.Created);

// 500
actionResult.Should().BeOfType<ObjectResult>()
    .Which.StatusCode.Should().Be((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```

Comment: This is nice, but still, it's 3rd party library and quite a radical change to unit testing once introduced to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `ExecuteAsync` method over `IHttpActionResult` object to get Http response of type `HttpResponseMessage` and then access `StatusCode` property to verify it.

You can also refer to these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) to know how `IHttpActionResult` works.

Comment: Your answer is correct for Web API 2. The OP however is for Asp.net-Core which would still apply. But you should find the docs from core to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionResult result = /* Your action result */;
int statusCode = (result as StatusCodeResult)?.StatusCode
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer with fluent assertions, but not everyone has access to those. If you need regular Assert statements, here's how that would look...

```
//setup
MyController controller = CreateController<MyController>();

//action
var actionResult = controller.Post(dafXml);

//assert
Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
var okResult = response.Result as OkObjectResult;
Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, okResult.StatusCode);
Assert.AreEqual("If a string is returned, it goes here", okResult.Value);
```

And I imagine this is how 201 and 500 would look (these are un-tested).

```
// 201
var createdResult = response.Result as CreatedResult;
Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.Created, createdResult.StatusCode);

// 500
var objectResult = response.Result as ObjectResult;
Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, objectResult.StatusCode);
```